# Compile filter argument specified non-existent file on windows phone 8.1 deployment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Just upgraded my OS from Windows 8.1 to 10 Pro and now I can no longer deploy apps to my Windows 8.1 phone.  Hardware is Microsoft Blu.

I cannot deploy from VS 2013 or  VS 2015 Community Editions.  Error I get in VS 2013 is:

Error   1   Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81030137  TrackuTransit.WindowsPhone

Meanwhile over in VS 2015, I get:

> Error: Compile filter argument specified non-existent file:
>   C:\dev\myapp\obj\Debug\MSIL\images\DarkIcons.dll
>   Invalid argument
>
> Microsoft (R) MDIL XAP Compiler - Version 4.0.0.0 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Usage: MDILXAPCompile /In: /Out:
>   /Config: [/CompileFilter:;]
>   [/Timeout:] [/Log:] [/AppX]
>
> /In       - Path to directory containing files to process /Out        - Path to
>   directory to place processed files in /Config     - Path to configuration
>   file /CompileFilter   - Optional restrictive list of assembly files in
>   InputPath,
>           separated by semi-colons, to be compiled. /Timeout    - Optional timeout in milliseconds before killing the Crossgen process. Overrides
>   config file timeout value. Use -1 for infinite timeout, 0 for
>   application default (2 hours). /Log       - Optional path to log file
>   /AppX     - Specifies that assemblies correspond to an AppX package
>
> Relative paths are relative to this executable's directory.

Interestingly enough, if phone is disconnected or locked, VS correctly recognizes this and reports the appropriate message.  If phone is unlocked, however, I get the above error.

**UPDATE:**

I located DarkIcons.dll under the images folder of the project and changed its **Copy To Output Directory** option from *None* to *Copy Always* but this did not seem to help either.

I also tried cheating by creating an images directory C:\dev\myapp\obj\Debug\MSIL\images and copying DarkIcons.dll to this folder, since it currently resides in C:\dev\myapp\obj\Debug\MSIL\

Lastly I removed DarkIcons from the project.  This time, there are no errors in the logs but deployment still fails.

Deployment went a little further but still failed.

Anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Did not want to spend any more time troubleshooting this.  Suspected an issue with corrupt manifest so just ended up creating a new Windows Phone 8.1 project and migrated all of my files from the corrupt project to the new one.

Think I am getting good at this migrations!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder bin in your project. 
`your project folder\bin`

Then rebuild it.

I also got the same issue but this solved my error.

**Update:** This is just a temporary solution. I found that the app won't work correctly if you do this. I downgraded to VS 2013 for development since many of the nugget package are not supported by Visual Studio 2015